# How is category description rendered in Shopware 6 storefront

Tags: frontend, twig, shopware6, storefront

This question might seem vague but I know how to work with `TWIG`. At the moment, I am trying to extend the **Category pages** and specifically **Category description** section in Shopware 6 storefront. But I can not find the `Category Description` block.

I was able to trace a block to the Category at `storefront/page/content/index.html.twig`

```
           {% block cms_content %}
                <div class="cms-page">
                    {% block page_content_blocks %}
                        {% sw_include "@Storefront/storefront/page/content/detail.html.twig" with {'cmsPage': page.cmsPage} %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            {% endblock %}
```

[image: Category Description (circled in red)]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the type of the CMS page.

```
{% block page_content_blocks %}
    {% if page.cmsPage.type == 'product_list' %}
        Change the world...
    {% else %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question with an image showing the category description block I'll like to extend but can not find.

Comment: There is no category description block. Categories are assigned a shopping experience layout. That layout defines the content including the description if they have one. If you want to hard code rendering a description you may overwrite the block as described, checking for the type to make the overwrite specific for product categories.

Answer (score -1):

The contents of the page you are editing are shopping experience elements.

Showing the category description is standard functionality in the shopping experiences module! Just duplicate the standard, add a text field and map it to the category description.

If you to edit it to your wishes, I recommend making a custom shopping experience element. You can find the documentation of this here:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/commerce/content/shopping-experiences-cms